# Word Request. Object with saddle shaped stress

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

I'm looking for a word to describe the type of hand-cuff straps used in, for example Avatar the film. They begin as a straight strip with a curve like a tape-measure, then when you "crack" them they curl around the wrist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have no idea about The Avatar, but your description reminded me of product for bicyclists. Apparently it is a reflective band that is called "Slap and Wrap", and you can [buy it on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002UUU0B2).

As far as I remember, they come as a solid piece, that is "slapped" over ankle or wrist. They are also called "[slap bracelets](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8395)".

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I'd seen them elsewhere, you've pinpointed it. Will wait the standard 24 hours to see if a single word turns up, meanwhile thanks.